# Position and momentum expectation values for the stationary states of the infinite square well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, potential

I'm really lost in figuring out how to solve the integral for the expectation value of $x$ and $x^2$

$$\int_0^a x \sin(\frac{n\pi}ax)^2 dx $$

**This equation is from the $n$th stationary state equation of the infinite square well after squaring the wavefunction.**

I'm just not sure what method to use to completely solve for the expectation value of $x$. I would like to see a step by step technique needed to understand how to approach these problems.

I'm using Griffiths Quantum Mechanics.
*I've already squared the wavefunction so the equation given above is what I need to solve to get the expectation value of $x$.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer contains a couple of simple techniques how to solve such averages.

For calculating $\langle x \rangle$ the best method is to change variables:

$ \text {(I)} \ x = y + a/2.$

You can check that for odd $n$ you get

$ \text {(II)} \ \int_{-a/2}^{a/2} \ y \cos ^2(\frac{n\pi \ y}a) dy, $

while for even $n$ you get

$ \text {(III)} \ \int_{-a/2}^{a/2} \ y \sin ^2(\frac{n\pi \ y}a) dy. $

After normalizing the wave-function (let $N$ be the norm) we get,

$ \text {(IV)} \ \langle x \rangle = \frac {1}{N^2} \int_{-a/2}^{a/2} \ y \cos ^2(\frac{n\pi \ y}a) dy + \frac {a}2 \frac {1}{N^2} \int_{-a/2}^{a/2} \cos ^2(\frac{n\pi \ y}a) dy = \frac {a}2. $

It's because the integrand in the 1st integral in the middle wing is anti-symmetrical, and because $N^2$ multiplied by the 2nd integral is equal to 1. The same if instead of cosine square we have sine square.

About the calculus of $\langle x^2 \rangle$ you can use Alfred's suggestion,

$ \text {(V)} \ \frac {1}{N^2} \int_0^a \ \frac {x^2}{2} [1 - \cos (\frac {2n\pi x}a)] dx = \frac {a^3}{6N^2} - \frac{1}{N^2} \int_0^a \frac {x^2}2 \cos (\frac {2n\pi x}a) dx .$

Now, we use a trick : notice that

$ \text {(VI)} \ N^2 = \int_0^{a} \ \frac {1}{2} [1 - \cos (\frac {2n\pi x}a)] dx = \frac {a}{2} .$ So, we get the norm

$\text {(VII)} \ N = \sqrt {\frac {a}{2}}.$

But, more important is another result : substituting in $ \text {(VI)}$, $a = 1/b$ we get

$ \int_0^{1/b} \ \frac {1}2 [1 - \cos (2n\pi bx)] dx = \frac {1}{2b} .$

Taking twice the derivative of both sides with respect to $b$

$ 2n^2 \pi^2\int_0^{1/b} \ x^2 \cos (2n\pi bx) dx = b^{-3} .$

Substituting now $b = 1/a$ you can use this result and the norm $\text {(VII)}$ in $ \text {(V)}$,

$ \text {(VIII)} \ \langle x^2 \rangle = \frac {a^2}{3} - \frac{a^2}{2n^2 \pi^2} .$